# How to create the progress indicator for the following process?

Tags: syntax, monitoring

Consider the code

```
Table1[m_]:=Table[{m,NIntegrate[Exp[-I*m*x],{x,0,1000}]},{i,0,8000,1}]
Table2=Join[Table1[1],Table1[5],Table1[0.2],Table1[0.08]]
```

How to create a progress indicator for the operation in the second row?

Comment: So like an indicator that says "2/4" when it's solving `Table1[5]`?

Comment: @C.E. Yes, that's what I want.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I have an idea. The realization, although stupid, is the following.

```
Table1[m_] := 
 Table[{m, NIntegrate[Exp[-I*m*x], {x, 0, 1000}]}, {i, 0, 80, 1}]
M := Association[{1 -> 1, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 0.2, 4 -> 0.08}]
Monitor[Table11 = Table[{Table1[M[j]]}, {j, 1, 4, 1}], 
 Row[{ProgressIndicator[j, {1, 4}], j}, " "]]
Table2 = Join[Table11[[1]], Table11[[2]], Table11[[3]], Table11[[4]]]
```